# Sql Phone Number Converter Function

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to create a function that takes a input like (289)648-0997 or 12896480997 abd just returns 2896480997

my code below works for the 12896480997 but not for (289)648-0997

```
Alter FUNCTION [dbo].[fnFormatPhoneNumber](@phoneNumber VARCHAR(24))
RETURNS VARCHAR(24)

BEGIN

    RETURN RIGHT(@phoneNumber, LEN(@phoneNumber) - 1) 

END
Go
```

Comment: Use `REPLACE` to remove   `(`, `)` and `-` then your good to go (depending on the logic of the leading 1)

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: @AlexK. can you write it. please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your function to this:

```
Alter FUNCTION [dbo].[fnFormatPhoneNumber](@phoneNumber VARCHAR(24))
RETURNS VARCHAR(24)

BEGIN
SET @phoneNumber = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@phoneNumber,'(',''),')',''),'-','')
RETURN RIGHT(@phoneNumber, 10) 

END
Go
```

`SELECT [dbo].[fnFormatPhoneNumber]('(289)648-0997')` 
 
AND 
`SELECT [dbo].[fnFormatPhoneNumber]('12896480997')` 
 both return: 
`2896480997`

Comment: it says replace function requires 3 arguments

Comment: @Alexander forgot a comma. Try it now.

Comment: for (289)648-0997 it returns -0997

Comment: Made an edit to the function, not sure why it returned that. I show what I am running and what the output is for me above.

Answer (score 0):

use a case when to distinguish between those that begin with 1 and those that dont.

```
return
case when left(@phonenumber,1) = 1 then
RIGHT(replace(replace(replace(@phoneNumber, '(',''),')',''),'-','') LEN(@phoneNumber) - 1)
else replace(replace(replace(@phoneNumber, '(',''),')','')'-','') end
```

if the first char is a 1 then remove it and replace the ()- with ''.
if not just replace the ()-

not too sure on the logic of your input, may be possible to do away with the replace part in the first case when if you wouldnt input a number with ()- and a leading 1.